# Javascript in an external file

Tags: php, javascript, html

Before I ask this question I must point out that I have tried to search for EVERYTHING!

My question is how can I run javascript from an external file instead of inside my php / html. What I'm trying to do is.

```
    function ClearForm() {
      document.form.message.value="";
    }

    function comeBack(){
      if (document.form.message.value == "") {
         document.form.message.value="What's on your mind?";
      }      
    }
```

I have included`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>` in the `<head>` and I have a file in the root called javascript.js and my php file is in the root too so that shouldn't be the problem! But how do I run that pieces of code you see above in the javascript.js file instead of in my php file. It work's fine if I have it in the php file but I want to separate things!

I have also tried to give the form / input field an id and then use getElementById in the external JavaScript file.

But as you can see and hear I'm kinda new to JavaScript so I'm apparently doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above code is the only thing in your Javascript.js file, then you need to call the functions to run the code.

You've included the external Javascript file correctly - however, because all of your JS is included within functions, these function/s must be called before the code will run.

A call to 'ClearForm()' or 'comeBack()' from within your PHP file should run the code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my self clear. I am calling the functions like this: `<textarea cols="80" rows="1" onfocus="ClearForm()" onBlur="comeBack()" name="message" maxlength="140">What's on your mind?<? echo $about_me; ?></textarea>`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand - so your other option would be to attach event handlers to the textarea etc after the page has loaded. That would mean that you don't have to include 'onBlur' and that kind of stuff within the HTML itself. Information on event handlers here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have tried that. And it doesn't make any difference, maybe it's because it can't find the "form" the name of the form I'm trying to call and it can't find "message" the textarea name? :/ You know what I mean?

Comment: As long as you give the form a unique ID property, and the same with the textarea, the JS should be able to find it, even if the JS is in an external file. I've just created a test to check that works, and it does. Ensure you're using document.getElementById to select the ID of the elements and then you should be able to do what you want with it. I wouldn't bother with the document.form stuff - just select the form directly by getElementById.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now, but I still have not included it properly. I just saw a "problem". I have a folder called includes where I have my html etc, so I dont have to repeat it all over the files. So I just call `include ('includes/html1.php');` etc. And the `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>` is inside the includes/html1.php in the `<head>` where my javascript file is in the root. So it should work if I add ../javascript to the src right? So I could call the javascript file from my index.php if it include the html1 file!

Comment: Aha, well if the path to the JS file is wrong then it definitely won't work! You could always include console.log("found file") in the JS file (outside a function), or use an alert() as someone below suggested, to check that the file is being included properly. If you sort that out, your code should work. It might also be better to not use relative paths (../javascript) and just use the direct URL to the javascript file instead - that way you won't have problems.

Comment: Yeees it is working now... :D Thank you very much... Another problem I had was I had `<script type="text/javascript"> alert('js file found OK!'); </script>` in my javascript file... Hmm /shy

Answer (score 1):

That JS file will have to be in the same folder as your PHP page.

Test whether the file is found or not by adding this line at the top of the js file

```
alert('js file found OK!');
```

document.form is an array, so if you only have one form use:

```
document.forms[0]
```

Also depending on which browser you use, find and install some Developer Tools to help you identify these errors.

Comment: How very DOM1: `document.forms[0]`

Comment: Thank you very mush for the tip, that was a easy way to check it :)

Comment: I wrote "That JS file will have to be in the same folder as your PHP page." because you had plain src="javascript.js". Generally scripts are kept in a /scripts folder (or /js) in the home directory and accessed src="/scripts/javascript.js" that way things are kept separate, much as you'd put images in /images folder.

Comment: I see.. I get it now thx :) but I just ment that alert('js file found OK!'); was a really easy way to check if I had linked correctly to my .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared those functions in the <head>. All fine.

The question is *when* do you want to *call/run* those functions?

If you simply want to run them at the end of the page, then you can add another external javascript file and include it using <script src="my_external_file.js"> right before the </body> tag.

Otherwise, you have to declare onXXX handlers, like `onLoad()` for the document, `onClick()` for certain elements, `onSubmit()` for forms, etc. These, too, can be declared in an external file, but specified after the relevant elements are loaded.